# C# string with special characters to MySQL varchar column

Tags: c#, mysql, database, special-characters

I'm trying to add the following string from a C# application to a varchar column in a MySQL database.

```
"TVCM ｜ AU「FULL CONTROL／XMAS」篇　60秒"
```

It ends up like this

```
"TVCM | au?FULL CONTROL/Xmas???60?"
```

I've set default-character-set=utf8 in my.ini and set the DEFAULT CHARSET to utf8 for the database, the tables and the columns.

The code for inserting the string looks like this
*(where title has the value `TVCM ｜ AU「FULL CONTROL／XMAS」篇　60秒`*

```
string sqlQuery = "insert into myTable (Title) values (?Title)";
MySqlCommand command = m_connection.CreateCommand();
m_connection.Open();
command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?Title", title));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
m_connection.Close();
```

Also, I'm using MySQL Connector.NET 6.6.4.

Any idea what my problem may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can also specify the charset in the connection string - check if your connection string explicitly specifies `"charset=utf8"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be in the charset of your development environment, the default file encoding of Visual Studio depends on the Windows setting. Following is the location That You can change it.

Control Panel | Regional and Language Options | Advanced | Inglês to change the language from the drop down list.